# moduleServer does not have the ... to add additional parameters to the module function like callModule

Tags: r, shiny

According to documentation:

> Note: As of Shiny 1.5.0, we recommend using moduleServer() instead of
> callModule(), because the syntax is a little easier to understand, and
> modules created with moduleServer can be tested with testServer().

But here is the docs for `callModule`:

> #### Usage
>
> ```
> callModule(module, id, ..., session = getDefaultReactiveDomain())
> ```
>
> #### Arguments
>
> - module   A Shiny module server function
> - id   An ID string that corresponds with the ID used to call the
>   module's UI function
> - ...  Additional parameters to pass to module server function
> - session  Session from which to make a child scope (the default should almost always be used)

And here is the docs for `moduleServer`:

> #### Usage
>
> ```
> moduleServer(id, module, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain())
> ```
>
> #### Arguments
>
> - id  An ID string that corresponds with the ID used to call the module's UI function.
> - module  A Shiny module server function.
> - session Session from which to make a child scope (the default should almost always be used).

How do I add additional parameters to the server function without the `...`?

Comment: See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313798/having-difficulty-nesting-action-button-inside-bs4card)

Comment: It does not demonstrate how to add additional parameters to the module function

Comment: The moduleServer lives inside a function you create which can have as many arguments as you need.

Comment: @TTS can you add an answer with an example then? pseudo code is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moduleServer` will live inside the server-side portion of the module you create. It contains only the `id` and the `module` itself.  The `employeeInfoServer` passes `id` as well as `employee_`.  This could pass any number of additional arguments such as `function(id, employee_, hair_color, eye_color, city)` etc...  Those variable are then accessible in the `moduleServer`

```
employeeInfoServer <- function(id, employee_) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$job_title<- renderUI({
        h3(users[match(employee_, users$Name), "Job Title"]) 
      })
    }
  )
}
```

...maybe this makes more sense.  `yourmoduleServer` is the server-side of the module you're creating.

```
yourmoduleServer <- function(id, ...) {
  moduleServer(id, module)
}
```

Comment: What if the module function has additional params like `module = function(input, output, session, param_1, param_2)`. In this case, how can moduleServer set `param_1` and `param_2`?